# Plot a Pandas DataFrame in a tkinter GUI with a secondary axis and set arguments

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, tkinter, axis

i have a DataFrame and i want to plot two columns of it in one plot. My Code is as follows:

```
x = df_Data_7370(start_date, end_date)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
x.plot(x="Diff_Rollkreis", y="Beugemoment", yticks=[0,2,4,6,8,10], 
xlabel='Diff. Rollkreis-Ø [mm]', ylabel='Beugemoment [Nm]', style='o', color='red', markersize=2, ax=ax)
x.plot(x="Diff_Rollkreis", y="Axialspiel", style='o', color='blue', markersize=2, ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = master)

canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=235,y=0)

canvas.draw()
```

My Problem is
-that i don't know how to name the second y-axis
-that i don't know how to set the ylim and yticks for the main and second axis individual. How can i say python, that ylim and yticks for the main axis and the second axis are different?

thank your for help

```
x = df_Data_7370(start_date, end_date)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
x.plot(x="Diff_Rollkreis", y="Beugemoment", yticks=[0,2,4,6,8,10], xlabel='Diff. Rollkreis-Ø [mm]', ylabel='Beugemoment [Nm]', style='o', color='red', markersize=2, ax=ax)
    x.plot(x="Diff_Rollkreis", y="Axialspiel", style='o', color='blue', markersize=2, ax=ax, secondary_y=True)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = master)
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=235,y=0)
canvas.draw()
```

Comment: do you would like two plot? code show that you want two plot.

Comment: Hi, actually I would like to create one plot.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a plot with two y-axes:

```py
import random
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

master = tk.Tk()

x_values = list(range(1, 101, 10))
y1_values = [random.randint(100, 1000) for _ in range(10)]
y2_values = [random.randint(1000, 10000) for _ in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
ax.plot(x_values, y1_values, color="red", marker="o")
ax.set_xlabel("X Values", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Y1 Values", fontsize=14, color="red")

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(x_values, y2_values, color="blue", marker="o")
ax2.set_ylabel("Y2 Values", fontsize=14, color="blue")

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=master)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

master.mainloop()
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: Hey acw1668, thank you for your helpf!